# how to set watermark when downloading from s3 bucket

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, watermark

I have one s3 bucket which contains zip files. 
I have a script which downloading the zip files to my local server, unzip them and upload them to another s3 bucket. 
How can I set watermark so i will know what was the last file i downloaded so i won't need to save all the files locally or download all the files each time the script is running ?
I'm using aws sync command which as much as i understand should copy only new files, am i right ?

```
aws s3 sync $gcs3$gcRegion/$gcTech/$gcPrinterFamily/$gcPrinterType/$gcPrinterName/  $dir
```

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command will copy any files that are not present in the destination (sort of).

So, you either need to keep all previously-downloaded files, or you need another way to keep track of the files that were downloaded.

Instead, I would recommend writing your own program that:

- Downloads all files from the S3 bucket with a `LastModified` timestamp after a stored timestamp
- Stores the current time
- Unzips the files and copies them to the other S3 bucket
- Deletes the zip files and unzipped files

So, the program will need to remember the last time it downloaded files, but it will not need to remember which files it downloaded. Be careful — S3 stores time in UTC, so you'll need to convert your timezones. Or, simply remember the highest `LastModified` value of the files you downloaded.

To obtain a list of files since a certain `LastModified` date, you could use the AWS CLI:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket jstack-a --query "Contents[?LastModified>='2019-04-11'].[Key]" --output text
```

However, I would recommend writing a Python program for the above activities, since it would be easier that writing command-line scripts.

Comment: "So, you either need to keep all previously-downloaded files, or you need another way to keep track of the files that were downloaded."
this is exactly what im asking - there is a possibility to add watermarks, im just don't know how

Comment: No. The `aws s3 sync` command does not keep a watermark. It determines the files to copy by looking at the files already in the destination. That's why you'll need to write your own program to pull files since a given time. You could use the above command to generate a list of files since a certain date, and then use that list in an `aws s3 cp` command, but things start to get messy that way. I'd recommend a Python script instead.

Comment: i'm not good with python so it will take me more time to do it
i know that sync not saving water mark, i have to do something to save the water mark